# What are the meanings of the characters between . and Z in the timestamp?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, timezone

When i generate a timestamp for example with the current date and time with

`new Date().toISOString()`

then i get the timestamp UTC from current date and time

`2021-03-23T11:45:16.939Z`

i know that T in the middle is just separator which should be there for the convention
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

and The Z stands for the Zero timezone, as it is offset by 0 from the
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#UTC

but i wonder

what are the meaning of the characters between the `.` sign and the letter `Z`

SO IN MY CASE - 939

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's milliseconds. So the time you've shown is **very nearly** 11:45:17. It's 11:45:16 and 939ms, meaning it's only 61ms away from being 11:45:17. From [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format):

> **`sss`** is the number of complete milliseconds since the start of the second as three decimal digits.

Comment: Thank you for the answer